# One controller action for both full postback and AJAX postback or split into two actions?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, postback

If we handle the normal (full) postback and AJAX postbacks in a single controller action it is very likely that the method will be huge. A lot of `if..else` sentences handling the returns (returning regular views vs partial views vs JSON success strings), different handling for `ModelState` errors, etc.

However, splitting it up into two actions, for instance `Create` and `CreateAjax` means that two instances of similar code will have to be maintained.

What do you recommend to keep the actions simple but still cover both postback scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have two methods, Create and CreateAjax and look at refactoring the code so any duplicate code was put into a helper class or a service.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest take all the code that is responsible for the ajax part to a separate `ActionResult` that looks clean.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, you can handle it with one action like:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(...)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return DoSomethingAjax(..);
    else
       return DoSomethingStandard(..);
}

private ActionResult DoSomethingAjax(..) { }

private ActionResult DoSomethingStandard(..) { }
```

You could create some factory component that does the work, and calls from the two methods:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    return DoSomethingFactory.Do();
}

public ActionResult DoSomethingAjax()
{
    return DoSomethingFactory.Do();
}
```

You can split the postback action handlers and the AJAX handlers by using a partial class.

Some ideas.

Comment: This is very similar to what I have now. It's valid answer but not an improvement.

Comment: @mare Well I have 2 solutions present... each code sample is different.

Comment: @mare And there aren't a ton of variations, so it may not be an improvement because it's a valid approach.